# Flutter firebaseauth sha

Tags: firebase, flutter, sha

Переустановил Windows. После этого скачал свой же проект с github. Пытаюсь пройти авторизацию, но ничего не происходит. Никаких ошибок абсолютно. Единственное, что отличаются SHA1/256 от тех которые были до переустановки windows. В самом проекте SHA менять нельзя. Что делать ума не приложу

Answer (score 0):

> В самом проекте SHA менять нельзя

Почему? У вас нет доступа к ЛК в firebase?

В release сборке авторизация будет работать с любым SHA.

Для debug сборок необходимо добавить свой SHA в настройках проекта - к сожалению, других вариантов нет.

[image: как добавить sha]

Comment: Я наверное плохо рассказал проблему. Суть в том что приложение на выходе не "обновляется" 
а конфликтует с версиями с другого пк.

Comment: Доступ к firebase есть.

Comment: А касательно вопроса произошёл какой-то баг.. У меня ни один проект не работал с Firebase. Сейчас всё хорошо. Но касательно "конфликта приложений" на разных пк я не знаю как с этим бороться).